# How to fix "plural forms could be dangerous" django error?

Tags: python, django, translation

I don't get it. If I set the `Accept-Language` header to anything other than "en" (de, pl, es) or even something that doesn't exist (like xxs), the app doesn't spit out this error, but it does when I set it to "en". It happens only on windows (newest gettext tools). Here's the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\projekty\python\myapp_api\_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\han
dlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\projekty\python\myapp_api\_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\han
dlers\base.py", line 244, in _legacy_get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "E:\projekty\python\myapp_api\_env\lib\site-packages\django\middlewa
re\locale.py", line 29, in process_request
    translation.activate(language)
  File "E:\projekty\python\myapp_api\_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\tr
anslation\__init__.py", line 161, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "E:\projekty\python\myapp_api\_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\tr
anslation\trans_real.py", line 238, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "E:\projekty\python\myapp_api\_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\tr
anslation\trans_real.py", line 227, in translation
    _translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
  File "E:\projekty\python\myapp_api\_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\tr
anslation\trans_real.py", line 129, in __init__
    self._add_installed_apps_translations()
  File "E:\projekty\python\myapp_api\_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\tr
anslation\trans_real.py", line 176, in _add_installed_apps_translations
    translation = self._new_gnu_trans(localedir)
  File "E:\projekty\python\myapp_api\_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\tr
anslation\trans_real.py", line 156, in _new_gnu_trans
    fallback=use_null_fallback)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\gettext.py", line 426, in translation
    t = _translations.setdefault(key, class_(fp))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\gettext.py", line 162, in __init__
    self._parse(fp)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\gettext.py", line 297, in _parse
    self.plural = c2py(plural)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\gettext.py", line 76, in c2py
    raise ValueError('plural forms expression could be dangerous')
ValueError: plural forms expression could be dangerous
```

I have `plural-forms` set up correctly in my `django.po` file:

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
```

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found an answer - the reason for that error is my incompetence :). I ran `django-admin makemessages` command in the root of my project, so next to _env and all the packages inside. This command created language files for a couple of projects with the default django.po file template, so they contained something like `plural-forms=INTEGER` and other stuff and this was causing the above error.

Comment: FYI: if you've removed all the default `plural-forms=INTEGER` lines from your PO files, and you're still getting this error, try removing all the compiled `*.mo` files.  Amusingly, `compilemessages` was failing for me due to already-compiled MO files containing the problem.

Comment: Yeap, I usually have my virtualenv folder in the root of my django projects, but this is triggering some nasty behaviour from the makemessages and compilemessages commands, so I guess I'll have to do that differently for projects with translations? Or maybe there's an ignore for these commands?

Answer (score 3):

Here I will give you all the details about Plural-forms:

See this link [Plural-forms](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html).It will helps to you.

> Note:This just [link](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/commit/4b6a9758396450651bc2d02b2c7d49bac6cd3f25) give a simple idea about plural

It surely helps to others

Answer (score 1):

Your plural expression `(n != 1)` is most likely considered dangerous because it's too inclusive. `n doesn't equal 1` means any value except `1` will evaluate to `True` including booleans, strings or `None`.

Try changing your expression to use equals, greater than and less than operations to narrow down the scope of the expression.

Comment: I think I should mention - I get this error with or without a translation file, so I don't think this expression is the reason, but I'll try.

Comment: I'm not certain, but the lack of a translation file may also be considered dangerous because then there would be on expression at all.

Comment: Ok, another reason why I think it won't work - for german language the line looks the same, but I still can send a request with `Accept-Language: de` and it will go through :/

Comment: Yep, doesn't work unfortunately. I mean - however I change this expression, I still get this error.